# RAWTherapee shows unedited photos with edited colors

Tags: photo-editing

I like to edit the same photo with different settings and save them under different names. Sometimes I get a menu that allows me to save under a new name, sometimes the photo is just saved, quite annoying.
But my main problem is that even the original unedited version (copied with Dolphin) is shown as if I had already edited it (in thumbnail and after opening, too), so I don't know if it is still the original and how changes affect it. Photos I never worked on are shown in the original colors but even a freshly copied version of one I once worked on look different. If I check them with Gwenview they look normal.
Can anybody help please. RAWTherapee seems to be great, but this annoys me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like Picasa, Rawtherapee makes non-destructive changes to an image.  A small sidecar file containing details of changes is stored in the same folder as the original but the original is untouched.  When you reload the original file into Rawtherapee the changes you made previously are read from the sidecar file and applied.  So you see the image as you last changed it.  If you load the original into an image viewer such as Gwenview the changes are not applied and you see the photo in its original state.  If you want to cancel changes made in Rawtherapee simply locate and delete the sidecar file - it has the extension .pp3.  Hope this helps.